# Reorganize Objects in OEM - Host Credentials do not have enough privileges

Tags: oracle, enterprise-manager, oracle-enterprise-manager

When I try to re-organize objects from OEM (11g) and enter my host credentials (not "oracle"), I get the message:

> "An error occurred verifying the host credentials. Make sure the
>   credentials are valid and that they specify an account with enough
>   privileges to write to the directory where the reorganization script
>   will be created. Credential verification error: ERROR: Invalid
>   username and/or password"

My host username is a member of the oinstall and dba groups.  I guess my first question is what directory is it that I need write access to?  My second question is what privileges do I need in order to run a reorg (not as the "oracle" user)?

I should say that this is a linux Oracle server.

Comment: It says invalid username or password?

Comment: Yes, I put the exact message that I received back.  The "invalid username and/or password" is strange since I know I am providing the correct values.  There doesn't seem to be any way to tell exactly what is happening here.

Comment: Did you ever sort this GregH? Im having the same issue with a tablespace that i cant shrink until i reorganise it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have different types of credentials in OEM !
First you need to create those credentials and test them. 
[See here an article that walks you throw how to create and test your named credentials](http://www.aodba.com/create-named-credentials-oem-12c/)